# How to link to an html file in the root directory in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I link to an html file in the root directory of a rails app in ruby?

```
<a href="foo.html" class="test" rel="foo">Hello</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just /foo.html for your href, put the file in public folder of app.